# Extern keyword on definition of static data members and member functions, C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, extern, linkage

Does C++ standard allow `extern` keyword on definition of static data members and member functions (provided that linkage matches) ? For example:

```
struct A
{
    static int a;    // external linkage
    void f();        // external linkage
};

extern int A::a;
extern void A::f() {}
```

Comment: have you missed the static off  `void f();` in the question?

Comment: Static member function as well as non-static has external linkage. When we use 'extern' at namespace scope it usually means external linkage. So the linkage should agree. GCC does not complain, but Visual Studio does.

Comment: It seems that if standard does not explicitly say that it is not allowed, than we are free to fill the gap with our own logic. For example if we use 'static' on member function definition GCC says that member function cannot have internal linkage.

Comment: Clang also complains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `extern` keyword is not allowed as a storage class specifier on class members. From [dcl.stc]/5:

> [...] The `extern` specifier cannot be used in the declaration of class members or function parameters. [...]

Moreover, definitions are declarations, cf. [basic.def]/2:

> A declaration is a *definition* unless [rules].

Therefore, the `extern` keyword is not allowed as a storage class specifier on any form of class member declaration, whether on the first declaration that's part of the class definition or on subsequent declarations that are part of out-of-line member definitions.